# dbWritetable RmySQL R Partial Data write back

Tags: r, rmysql

Previously everything was working fine but suddenly one day only partial data is getting write down to a table.

So for example if I want to write 6000 rows to table using dbWritetable in R, 5000 rows only are getting written back.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: From the official close reasons: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_.